# How to move specific documents from one mongoose model schema to other?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mern, mongoose-populate

I am trying to create an OTP verification process wherein through the signup route, the user will enter the signup details such as phone number, gender. The function will save the data along with an OTP to an OTPdata model schema. In the verifyOtp route, the user will enter the OTP, and the function will check if the otp already exists, if it does, it will copy the whole document to other User model. I don't know how to copy documents of one model to other based on certain condition (if it has the same the otp the user entered). Can anyone help me? Or is there any better approach?

Comment: Why do you want to copy the data? 

Have you tried this approach where the account is created but not verified and when user enters the correct OTP the account is verified and active?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @HandsomeCoder Hey, so I thought of that approach, but I am not sure how to check for existing users in this case. My approach would be to check for existing user by checking if the number A- already exists in the database and B- if the OTP is verified. What do you suggest? I am new to backend, thank you for being patient. I did eventually solve the problem by creating two schemas and deleting it from the OTPschema once verified.